# How to DATE_TRUNC by 10 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called payments with information of all payments made by client for the certain
period of time like displayed below:

```
Client_id             sum                  date
2345                   50$             2020-11-20
4556                   20$             2020-12-01
3434                   30$             2020-10-07
5667                   10$             2020-11-15
2346                   25$             2020-12-06
5667                   60$             2020-12-16
```

And I need to find all the payments made by clients with interval of 10 days(for certain period
of time), like:

```
Client_id                     sum            Interval_of_payments
2345                          50$          2020-11-13 to 2020-11-22
4556                          20$          2020-12-01 to 2020-12-10
2346                          25$          2020-12-03 to 2020-12-12
```

But the day is not always starting from the first day of the month.

I wrote query, but it returns by `week`:

```
select payments.client_id, sum(payments.sum), DATE_TRUNC('week', date)
from payments 
where payments.date between '2020-11-01' and '2020-12-31'
group by 1,3
```

All in all I want it to work like `DATE_TRUNC('10 days')`

Comment: I don't understand why you have 3 rows for client_id = 2345? There is only one row with that client_id in your sample data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited rows to make it sense, but I have for the same client_id different purchases in different time. But it does not change anything. The main question was to find a way to date_trunc for `10 days` instead of `week`

Comment: Ok, 2021 year started at friday, 5th day of week. At which day of your 10-days period 2021 year started? In other words: you need to specify the algorythm how the (theoretically infinite) timeline should be splitted to 10-days periods. How to get the number of day in the 0-9 or 1-10 interval for any specified date?

Comment: @Abelisto for example if we take start date 2020-11-02, and i need to find sum of `sum` of clients for the next every 10 days. Like `2020-11-02 - 2020-11-11`, `2020-11-12 - 2020-11-21` ... so on until the present time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the difference between any date and some canonical and then use *arithmetic* for the calculation.

The following is the calculation for the period counter and the start and end dates of the period:

```
select p.*,
       (p.date - v.date) / 10 as period_counter,
       v.date + ( (p.date - v.date) / 10 ) * interval '10 day') as period_start,
       v.date + (9 +  (p.date - v.date) / 10 ) * interval '10 day') as period_end
from payments p cross join
     (values ('2020-11-02'::date)) v(date);
```

This appears to answer the question that you actually asked.

Answer (score 2):

Simple arithmetic could be used:

```
create function date_trunc(start_date date, period int, the_date date)
    returns date
    stable strict
    language sql
as $$
    select the_date - ((the_date - start_date) % period)
$$;
```

Lets test it:

```
select
    date_trunc('2020-11-02', 10, '2020-11-05'),
    date_trunc('2020-11-02', 10, '2020-11-20'),
    date_trunc('2020-11-02', 10, '2020-12-06');

┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ date_trunc │ date_trunc │ date_trunc │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 2020-11-02 │ 2020-11-12 │ 2020-12-02 │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Note that for `2020-12-06` it should be `2020-12-02`, not `2020-12-03` as in your example.